# Pivot table in SAS

Tags: sas, pivot-table, enterprise-guide

The data looks as following:

```
YEAR    MONTH   ID1 ID2 FIELD   FIELD_DESC
2017    4   123 2222    FFF red1
2017    4   123 2222    FFG red2
2017    4   224 2221    XYZ green1
2017    4   225 1234    TYU blue5
```

and desired output is

```
YEAR    MONTH   ID1 ID2 blue5   green1  red1    red2
2017    4   123 2222    0   0   1   1
2017    4   224 2221    0   1   0   0
2017    4   225 1234    1   0   0   0
```

On SQL server I used to run the following:

```
select year, month, id1, id2, [field1], [field2] .... [fieldn]
from (select year, month, id1, id2, field, field_desc from source_table) P
Pivot (count(field) for field_desc in ([field1], [field2] .... [fieldn])) Pvt
```

The above would give me counts of field of each possible description by year, month, id1, id2.

I'm trying to translate this to SAS.

One approach would be conditional sums

```
proc sql;
create table aggr_table as 
select year, month, id1, id2,
sum(case when field_desc = 'field1' then 1 else 0 end) as field1
...
sum(case when field_desc = 'fieldn' then 1 else 0 end) as fiendn
from source_table 
group by year, month, id1, id2;
quit;
```

Second way I tried to do it was by

```
proc sort data = source_table
 by year descending month descending id1 descending id2;
run;

data table_aggr (keep year month id1 id2 field1 .... fieldn);
set source_table
retain field1
....
fieldn 0);

if field_desc = 'field1' then do;
field1 = field1 +1;
end;
....
if field_desc = 'fieldn' then do;
fieldn = fieldn + 1;
end;

if last.id2 then 
output;
by year month id1 id2;
run;
```

But the second way does not seem to work

> ERROR: BY variables are not properly sorted on data set
>   WORK.SOURCE_TABLE

My questions:
1) My googling so far seems to indicate preference for doing this kind of data manipulation in the data step rather than proc sql step, is there a particular advantage ?

2) What did I do wrong in the data step ?

3) Is there a better way to replicate the SQL code at the top of the post ? Both SAS options I'm looking at look rather unwieldy compared to SQL original.

Thank you
Ben

Comment: It's hard to see what you're trying to do without any data. But I suspect you really need a proc means/transpose or proc tabulate here. If you post data before and after it would help.

Comment: Your code is missing a number of semi-colons, for example in your PROC SORT step.. DId you get errors about that before the error message you posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PROC SUMMARY to count for you and then use PROC TRANSPOSE to turn the counts into variables instead of observations. If you just do it directly then you will get missing values instead of zero for the combinations that do not appear. You could post-process the file to replace the missing counts with zeros.  Or use the method below to build a CLASSDATA table to feed to PROC SUMMARY to insure that all of zeros are included before the transpose.

```
proc sql noprint ;
 create table classdata as
 select *
 from (select distinct year,month,id1,id2 from have) a
    , (select distinct field_desc from have) b
 ;
quit;
proc summary data=have nway classdata=classdata exclusive ;
  class year month id1 id2 field_desc ;
  output out=counts ;
run;
proc transpose data=counts out=want(drop=_name_);
  by year month id1 id2 ;
  id field_desc ;
  var _freq_;
run;
```

You could have PROC SQL generate the full rank counts directly with a little bit of tricky SQL.  Combine the data with the full list of the id variable values and count how many times the two id variables match.

```
proc sql noprint ;
 create table counts as
 select year,month,id1,id2
      , b.field_desc
      , sum(a.field_desc=b.field_desc) as count
 from have a
    , (select distinct field_desc from have) b
 group by year,month,id1,id2,b.field_desc
 order by year,month,id1,id2,b.field_desc
 ;
quit;
```

Generating the SQL is easy.  If the number of derived variables is small then just generate the code into a macro variable. (If the list is large then generate the code using a data step using either `call execute()` or by writing it to a file and using `%include` to run it.)

```
proc sql noprint ;
 select distinct
 catx(' '
     ,'sum(field_desc ='
     ,quote(trim(field_desc))
     ,') as'
     ,nliteral(field_desc)
     )
   into :code separated by ','
   from have
 ;
 create table want as
   select year, month, id1, id2
        , &code
   from have
   group by year, month, id1, id2
  ;
quit;
```

If you want to do it in a data step then look into using HASH object to gather that data.  Then use PROC TRANSPOSE or a code generation technique (like in the SQL above) to transform from observations to variables.

Comment: Yup, this did it precisely. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is what SAS offers PROCs for.

The `CLASS` statement in most procs (`proc means`,`proc tabulate` in particular) lets you summarize by various levels.  So for example:

```
proc means data=sashelp.class;
  var height weight;  *the numeric variables you are calculating with;
  class age sex;      *the grouping variables;
  types () age sex age*sex;   *the interactions you want - or use NWAY or WAYS;
run;
```

Or:

```
proc tabulate data=sashelp.class;
  var height weight;   *numeric variables to calculate with;
  class age sex;       *grouping variables;
  tables (all age sex age*sex),(height weight)*n;
run;
```

Depending on the proc, you have multiple ways to then get this information.  Many have an `out` option or `output` statement (e.g. `PROC MEANS` has `OUTPUT` statement to do this).  Additionally, `ODS OUTPUT` lets you get access to basically anything that's printed on the screen in table form.

```
ods output table=want;
proc tabulate data=sashelp.class;
  var height weight;
  class age sex;
  tables (all age sex age*sex),(height weight)*n;
run;
ods output close;
```

--or--

```
proc tabulate data=sashelp.class out=want;
  var height weight;
  class age sex;
  tables (all age sex age*sex),(height weight)*n;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you. I need the results in table to be used in the next step of the script. I'm not sure how I'd access the output of proc tabulate.

Comment: Still cant get it work. Tabulate is close but no cigar.  Year, Month, ID1, ID2 all show up on different rows instead of same row as needed.

Comment: `PROC TRANSPOSE` will fix that for you (as Tom largely shows).